# Can't install MariaDB 5.5 or 10 in Ubuntu 12.04. MYSQLD Failed to start?

Tags: 12.04, server, mysql, mariadb

I tried o install MariaDB on my Ubuntu 12.04 server. First it gave dependency issues and I fixed it by following this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16214517/installing-mariadb-unmet-dependencies-mariadb-server-5-5

But when installing mariadb-server, it fails to start the mysqld. Here is the apt log :

```
    root@sinha:/etc/apt# sudo apt-get install mariadb-server
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    The following extra packages will be installed:
      libdbd-mysql-perl libmariadbclient18 libmysqlclient18 mariadb-client-10.0 mariadb-client-core-10.0 mariadb-common mariadb-server-10.0 mariadb-server-core-10.0 mysql-common
    Suggested packages:
      tinyca mailx mariadb-test
    The following NEW packages will be installed:
      libdbd-mysql-perl libmariadbclient18 mariadb-client-10.0 mariadb-client-core-10.0 mariadb-common mariadb-server mariadb-server-10.0 mariadb-server-core-10.0
    The following packages will be upgraded:
      libmysqlclient18 mysql-common
    2 upgraded, 8 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
    Need to get 30.8 MB of archives.
    After this operation, 105 MB of additional disk space will be used.
    Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
    Get:1 http://mirrors.supportex.net/mariadb/repo/10.0/ubuntu/ precise/main mysql-common all 10.0.1-mariadb1~precise [8,826 B]
    Get:2 http://mirrors.supportex.net/mariadb/repo/10.0/ubuntu/ precise/main mariadb-common all 10.0.1-mariadb1~precise [3,304 B]
    Get:3 http://lk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main libdbd-mysql-perl amd64 4.020-1build2 [106 kB]
    Get:4 http://mirrors.supportex.net/mariadb/repo/10.0/ubuntu/ precise/main libmariadbclient18 amd64 10.0.1-mariadb1~precise [846 kB]
    Get:5 http://mirrors.supportex.net/mariadb/repo/10.0/ubuntu/ precise/main libmysqlclient18 amd64 10.0.1-mariadb1~precise [2,956 B]
    Get:6 http://mirrors.supportex.net/mariadb/repo/10.0/ubuntu/ precise/main mariadb-client-core-10.0 amd64 10.0.1-mariadb1~precise [1,814 kB]
    Get:7 http://mirrors.supportex.net/mariadb/repo/10.0/ubuntu/ precise/main mariadb-client-10.0 amd64 10.0.1-mariadb1~precise [5,103 kB]
    Get:8 http://mirrors.supportex.net/mariadb/repo/10.0/ubuntu/ precise/main mariadb-server-core-10.0 amd64 10.0.1-mariadb1~precise [5,517 kB]
    Get:9 http://mirrors.supportex.net/mariadb/repo/10.0/ubuntu/ precise/main mariadb-server-10.0 amd64 10.0.1-mariadb1~precise [17.4 MB]
    Get:10 http://mirrors.supportex.net/mariadb/repo/10.0/ubuntu/ precise/main mariadb-server all 10.0.1-mariadb1~precise [2,992 B]
    Fetched 30.8 MB in 1s (17.0 MB/s)      
    Preconfiguring packages ...
    (Reading database ... 119368 files and directories currently installed.)
    Preparing to replace mysql-common 5.5.31-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 (using .../mysql-common_10.0.1-mariadb1~precise_all.deb) ...
    Unpacking replacement mysql-common ...
    Selecting previously unselected package mariadb-common.
    Unpacking mariadb-common (from .../mariadb-common_10.0.1-mariadb1~precise_all.deb) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package libmariadbclient18.
    Unpacking libmariadbclient18 (from .../libmariadbclient18_10.0.1-mariadb1~precise_amd64.deb) ...
    Preparing to replace libmysqlclient18 5.5.31-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 (using .../libmysqlclient18_10.0.1-mariadb1~precise_amd64.deb) ...
    Unpacking replacement libmysqlclient18 ...
    Selecting previously unselected package libdbd-mysql-perl.
    Unpacking libdbd-mysql-perl (from .../libdbd-mysql-perl_4.020-1build2_amd64.deb) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package mariadb-client-core-10.0.
    Unpacking mariadb-client-core-10.0 (from .../mariadb-client-core-10.0_10.0.1-mariadb1~precise_amd64.deb) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package mariadb-client-10.0.
    Unpacking mariadb-client-10.0 (from .../mariadb-client-10.0_10.0.1-mariadb1~precise_amd64.deb) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package mariadb-server-core-10.0.
    Unpacking mariadb-server-core-10.0 (from .../mariadb-server-core-10.0_10.0.1-mariadb1~precise_amd64.deb) ...
    Processing triggers for man-db ...
    Setting up mysql-common (10.0.1-mariadb1~precise) ...
    Installing new version of config file /etc/mysql/my.cnf ...
    Setting up mariadb-common (10.0.1-mariadb1~precise) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package mariadb-server-10.0.
    (Reading database ... 119534 files and directories currently installed.)
    Unpacking mariadb-server-10.0 (from .../mariadb-server-10.0_10.0.1-mariadb1~precise_amd64.deb) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package mariadb-server.
    Unpacking mariadb-server (from .../mariadb-server_10.0.1-mariadb1~precise_all.deb) ...
    Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
    ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
    Processing triggers for man-db ...
    Setting up libmysqlclient18 (10.0.1-mariadb1~precise) ...
    Setting up libdbd-mysql-perl (4.020-1build2) ...
    Setting up libmariadbclient18 (10.0.1-mariadb1~precise) ...
    Setting up mariadb-client-core-10.0 (10.0.1-mariadb1~precise) ...
    Setting up mariadb-client-10.0 (10.0.1-mariadb1~precise) ...
    Setting up mariadb-server-core-10.0 (10.0.1-mariadb1~precise) ...
    Setting up mariadb-server-10.0 (10.0.1-mariadb1~precise) ...
     * Stopping MariaDB database server mysqld                                                                                                                                                              [ OK ] 
    130427 13:43:14 [Note] Plugin 'InnoDB' is disabled.
    130427 13:43:14 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
     * Starting MariaDB database server mysqld                                                                                                                                                              [fail] 
    invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
    dpkg: error processing mariadb-server-10.0 (--configure):
     subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mariadb-server:
     mariadb-server depends on mariadb-server-10.0; however:
      Package mariadb-server-10.0 is not configured yet.
    dpkg: error processing mariadb-server (--configure):
     dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
    ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
    No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
     mariadb-server-10.0
     mariadb-server
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Tried re installing mariadb-server, purged everything... removed mysql packages, installed mariadb-server-5.5... Nothing works.

Answer (score 14):

This worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql* mariadb*
```

Comment: Maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18375856/mariadb-replication-does-not-work/18375857#18375857

Answer (score 4):

Just fixed the problem by purging mysql* and mariadb*. Then removing all the traces of mysql by searching :

```
find / -name mysql*
```

There were some leftovers in lib. After removing them, rebooted the server and installed mariadb again! It worked.

Comment: This fixed it for me! I purged mysql* and mariadb*, removed a /var/lib/mysql directory and rebooted. MariaDB then installed fine. Thank you :)

Comment: this didn't help me until I `# apt-get upgrade` whole system

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when attempting to install MariaDB 10 in Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS, and neither of the other solutions worked for me. The root cause turned out to be a lack of memory (I had a VPS with 512MB).

I found this out by looking in `/var/log/syslog` after attempting to install MariaDB, and I saw this:

```
mysqld_safe[29684]: InnoDB: mmap(274726912 bytes) failed; errno 12
mysqld_safe[29684]: 140420 17:11:03 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
mysqld_safe[29684]: 140420 17:11:03 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
mysqld_safe[29684]: 140420 17:11:03 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
mysqld_safe[29684]: 140420 17:11:03 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
mysqld_safe[29684]: 140420 17:11:03 [Warning] Failed to load slave replication state from table mysql.gtid_slave_pos: 1146: Table 'mysql.gtid_slave_pos' doesn't exist
mysqld_safe[29684]: ERROR: 1146  Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist
mysqld_safe[29684]: 140420 17:11:03 [ERROR] Aborting
mysqld_safe[29684]:
mysqld_safe[29684]: 140420 17:11:03 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Note: I've removed the date/time and my hostname from the beginning of each log line.

I then [created a swap file](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-12-04) (256MB was enough) and ran:

`sudo aptitude install -f`

Which finished the install.

I don't know if every instance of this error could be fixed in the same way, but given EAPubs' answer involved rebooting the server, I wonder if that was the real fix: freeing up memory by rebooting.

Comment: I had the same error and log entries, however, I was able to get around them by doing a good old-fashioned `reboot` instead of creating swap.

Comment: @Paul in that case, I imagine that after rebooting you had enough free memory for the install to go ahead without the need for swap.

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to let others who find this solution to be aware that they may be able to get away with a simpler one. (I have to admit that I forget about such simple things sometimes.)

Answer (score 1):

I've just solved this problem. The root of all that mess was in this message :
"invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed."

Here are the steps :

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql* mariadb*
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Some install packages were "stuck" :

```
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/mariadb*
```

**These symbolic links were pointing to missing files**

```
sudo rm /etc/systemd/system/mysqld.service
sudo rm /etc/systemd/system/mysql.service
```

Finally, this worked :

```
sudo apt-get install mariadb-server
```

Answer (score 0):

While my current distro is 14.04, My fix should be relevant for similar issues.

I ran into this dependency/can't configure mariadb problem trying to clone my mysql/ onto a new install - didn't work.

**My fix:**

```
 - cd /var/lib
 - sudo service mysql stop
 - sudo cp -R mysql _mysql
 - sudo apt-get purge mysql* mariadb*
 - sudo rm -R mysql
 - sudo apt-get install mariadb-client mariadb-server
 - sudo cp -Ruv _mysql/. mysql/.
 - sudo mysql -u root -p ididityay! show databases
 - :D
 - sudo rm -R _mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

I posted my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/856229/166513) but here it is again because I wasted a couple of hours to find a solution (it is obvious now but...).

You need to specify version for mysql (dependencies) packets.

```
apt-get install mariadb-server mysql-common=10.1.19+maria-1~trusty libmysqlclient18=10.1.19+maria-1~trusty
```

You can get versions with

```
apt-cache policy mysql-common
```

You can always rollback with

```
apt-get remove --purge mysql* mariadb*
```

If you don't have any data or special config do also

```
rm -R /etc/mysql
rm -R /varl/lib/mysql
```