# Installing MariaDB fails

Tags: software-installation, mariadb

I am trying to solve this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/fideloper/Vaprobash/issues/225) (Vaprobash). (If you got Vagrant setup then you could try it out yourself and see the error in more detail.)

The script I am using can be found here: [mariadb.sh on github](https://github.com/fideloper/Vaprobash/blob/master/scripts/mariadb.sh). It's based on the official installation guide found [here](https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/#distro_release=precise&version=10.0&mirror=supportex&distro=Ubuntu), only with 2 added configuration for setting a password of choice.

I also tried installing it manually by fallowing the official guide, but that gave me the same result.

So far I tried a "solution" given [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286476/cant-install-mariadb-5-5-or-10-in-ubuntu-12-04-mysqld-failed-to-start) on another Askubuntu Question. It suggested running `sudo apt-get purge mysql* mariadb*`, but this didn't help either (I ran this before fallowing the official installation guide).

Does anyone got a idea what's going on? I can post the error's here, but I rather refer you to the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/fideloper/Vaprobash/issues/225).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a terminal and issue the following commands:

`apt-get purge mysql* mariadb*`

`apt-get install mariadb-client-10.0`

`apt-get install mariadb-server-10.0`

source:https://github.com/fideloper/Vaprobash/issues/225

Comment: This issue was eventually resolved by it self, probably by the MariaDB team. But I guess for future reference it's nice to have the above answer here as well. I will accept it as the answer, although it wasn't one for me.