# KDE error while upgrade

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, kde, mariadb

A few days ego, I updated my system KDE from 16.10 to 17.04 with `sudo do-release-upgrade -d`. After the update, there were and a small error, and since then, every time I try to update my system with `sudo apt-get upgrade`, I am having this error message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Setting up mariadb-server-10.1 (10.1.22-3) ...
dpkg: error processing package mariadb-server-10.1 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mariadb-server:
 mariadb-server depends on mariadb-server-10.1 (>= 10.1.22-3); however:
  Package mariadb-server-10.1 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mariadb-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 mariadb-server-10.1
 mariadb-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have tried many solutions like [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/286476/600715), but none of then seem to be working for me. Can some help, at least tell me where to begin ?

**updated**

Comment: No, you did *not* upgrade to 17.04 with `apt-get dist-upgrade`, it simply does not do that. You may have upgraded at some point but by other means. And the "many solutions" you may have tried (doubtfully) from the old, not applicable, linked question couldn't have corrected it because it's *not* the same error.

Comment: @CelticWarrior sorry  I pasted the wrong command.